# Category(#69942071276340) expected, got String(#8940340)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, slim-lang

I'm trying to submit a form for my rails app but I'm getting the error in the title and I'm not entirely sure how to fix it. Category is my foreign key.

```
= form_for @menu_price do |f|
  - if @menu_price.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@menu_price.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this menu_price from being saved:"
      ul
        - @menu_price.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message

  .form-group
    = f.label :category
    = f.select :category, options_for_select(@categories.map{ |c| [c.name] })
  .form-group
    = f.label :price
    = f.number_field :price
  .form-group
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description
  .form-group
    = f.label :serves
    = f.text_field :serves

  = f.submit
  = link_to 'Back', menu_prices_path, class:'button'
```

My models look like this

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :menu_prices
    validates :category, :presence => true
end
```

***********Updated***********

```
 class CreateMenuPrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :menu_prices do |t|
          t.text :description, :null => false 
          t.decimal :price , :default => nil , :null => true 
          t.string :serves, :default => nil  , :null => true 
          t.integer :small , :default => nil , :null => true 
          t.integer :regular, :default => nil , :null => true 
          t.integer :large, :default => nil , :null => true 
          t.integer :party, :default => nil, :null => true 

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
          add_reference :menu_prices, :categories
      end
    end
```

I understand that it wants a foreign key but I'm not sure how to go about submitting the foreign key in the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
******UPDATE******
My schema.rb is below

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "menu_prices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "description",   null: false
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.string   "serves"
    t.integer  "small"
    t.integer  "regular"
    t.integer  "large"
    t.integer  "party"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "categories_id"
  end

end
```

Comment: not sure if it's important but I am using rails V4.2

Comment: Can we get full backtrace?

Comment: Have you tried to load the Category in the controller from the received params?

Comment: @Nerian i'm not sure where I'd post that

Comment: @ThyagoB.Rodrigues not sure how I would do that sorry still new to this

Comment: Something like "@category = Category.find(menu_price_params[:category])" on your [probably] MenuPrice#create controller action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're actually passing only category_id from view (and not whole `Category` object), instead of

```
f.label :category
```

and

```
f.select :category
```

you should have:

```
f.label :category_id
```

and

```
f.select :category_id
```

You should also make sure `category_id` column is present in `menu_prices` table.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question but isn't the "add_foreign_key :categories, :menu_prices" suppose to create that column ?

Comment: @ArkhamRejek not exactly - you should have `add_foreign_key :menu_prices, :categories`.

Comment: so it should be add_column :menu_prices, :categories  or add_reference ?

Comment: I added my schema.rb to the OP

Comment: @ArkhamRejek according to the documentation, `add_foreign_key :menu_prices, :categories` should do its job.

Comment: when I use add_foreign the the it doesn't create the additional column in the table while add_reference does

Comment: added  t.belongs_to :category, index:true in my migration and it created the column for category_Id thanks man